# What's the meaning of " on to a major tool"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What's the meaning of " on to a major tool" in following sentence?

'So, on to a major tool I would like to start by speaking.'

Comment: Where did you hear/read this? What is the context? I'm struggling to make sense of it.

Comment: I read this in a book about business. The writer used this sentence before sharing an idea and his experience about that. You can replace the word "speaking" with "sharing".

Comment: It's a "reduced" form of something like *So, **let us move** on to a major tool I would like to start by speaking*. That kind of omission (of the highlighted words) is syntactically perfectly acceptable in English. But the clause *I would like to start by speaking* is ***not*** syntactically valid. It's clumsy phrasing anyway (use either ***[I will move] on to X*** OR ***I would like to start [with X]***, but not both in the same utterance. But more seriously, it ***needs*** a preposition - *So, [let me move] on to a major tool [that] I would like to start by speaking **about***.

Comment: Infinity90: - you should note that your example would be syntactically fine if it used the word ***sharing***, but it's NOT grammatical to have ***speaking*** there without a preposition such as ***about***. You can ***share a tool***, but you can't ***speak a tool***.

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica: Thanks a lot for your help.